# Elasticsearch .net Client Nest querycontainer always null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

Trying to filter results dynamically in a function by building a querycontainer which is always null. I don't undestand why because when I debug, I see that q variable is filled within the function but when I check the value of it, it is always null. Example code is below. Do you have any idea what I do wrong?

Thank you.

QueryContainer q = null;

```
        if (!ProductType.HasValue || (ProductType.HasValue && ProductType.Value == B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT))
        {
            q = Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t.Field(u => u.ProductTypeID == B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT));
            q &= Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t.Field(u => u.Stocks.Any() ? u.Stocks.Any(z => z.StatusID == B2CVariables.STATUS_PRODUCT_ONLINE && (!z.CheckStockStatus || (z.CheckStockStatus && z.CurrentStockCount > 0))) : false));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of the query is not correct [according to the signature of a `Term` query constructed with the static `Query<T>` type](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/2.x/src/Nest/QueryDsl/Query.cs#L173-L180).

`Field(Func<T, object>)` is a strongly typed expression to get the field that the query should operate on and the **value** with which the field must match for a term query should be specified using `.Value(object value)`. Here's an examplem assuming the following setup

```
public static class B2CVariables
{
    public const int PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT = 2;

    public const int STATUS_PRODUCT_ONLINE = 1;
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public IList<Stock> Stocks { get; set;}

    public int ProductTypeID { get; set;}
}

public class Stock
{
    public int StatusID { get; set;}

    public bool CheckStockStatus { get; set;}

    public int CurrentStockCount { get; set;}
}
```

The query

```
if (!ProductType.HasValue || (ProductType.HasValue && ProductType.Value == B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT))
{
    q = Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t
            .Field(u => u.ProductTypeID)
            .Value(B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT));

    q &= Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t
             .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().StatusID)
             .Value(B2CVariables.STATUS_PRODUCT_ONLINE)) && 
         (Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t
              .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().CheckStockStatus)
              .Value(false)) ||          
         (Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t
             .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().CheckStockStatus)
             .Value(true)) && 
          Query<ProductModel>.Range(t => t
              .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().CurrentStockCount)
              .GreaterThan(0))));
}
```

`u.Stocks.First().StatusID` is an *expression* to get a status id of a child object on `ProductModel`; the fact that we used `.First()` doesn't mean that we are asking for the *first* status id, it's just an expression that determines how to access status id in a concise manner. See the section on [field inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/field-inference.html#_complex_field_name_expressions) for more details.

Because `Query<T>.Term(t => t.Field(u => u.Field).Value(value))` can get long winded when combining many queries, there is a shorthand `Query<T>.Term(t => t.Field, value)` that can be used instead (*it's shorter in practice, even if it looks almost the same in this example due to indentation!*)

```
if (!ProductType.HasValue || (ProductType.HasValue && ProductType.Value == B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT))
{
    q = Query<ProductModel>.Term(
            t => t.ProductTypeID, 
            B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT);

    q &= Query<ProductModel>.Term(
             t => t.Stocks.First().StatusID, 
             B2CVariables.STATUS_PRODUCT_ONLINE) && 
         (Query<ProductModel>.Term(
             t => t.Stocks.First().CheckStockStatus, 
             false) ||       
         (Query<ProductModel>.Term(
             t => t.Stocks.First().CheckStockStatus, 
             true) && 
          Query<ProductModel>.Range(t => t
              .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().CurrentStockCount)
              .GreaterThan(0))));
}
```

Both produce the following query

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "term": {
          "productTypeID": {
            "value": 2
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "stocks.statusID": {
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "stocks.checkStockStatus": {
                  "value": false
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "stocks.checkStockStatus": {
                        "value": true
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "stocks.currentStockCount": {
                        "gt": 0.0
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, this query is probably not going to do what you want; Because there is a `bool` query that combines two queries across a child object (a `term` query on `checkStockStatus` and a `range` on `currentStockcount`), [the `Stock` object should be modelled as a `nested` object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) such that a match for both queries must be from the *same* stock object.

Once modeled as a nested object, the query would become

```
int? ProductType = 2;
QueryContainer q = null;

if (!ProductType.HasValue || (ProductType.HasValue && ProductType.Value == B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT))
{
    q = Query<ProductModel>.Term(t => t
        .Field(u => u.ProductTypeID)
        .Value(B2CVariables.PRODUCTTYPE_PRODUCT));

    q &= Query<ProductModel>.Nested(n => n
            .Path(u => u.Stocks.First())
            .Query(nq => nq
                .Term(t => t
                    .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().StatusID)
                    .Value(B2CVariables.STATUS_PRODUCT_ONLINE)) &&

                (nq.Term(t => t
                    .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().CheckStockStatus)
                    .Value(false)) ||
                (nq.Term(t => t
                    .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().CheckStockStatus)
                    .Value(true)
                ) && nq.Range(t => t
                    .Field(u => u.Stocks.First().CurrentStockCount)
                    .GreaterThan(0)
                )))
            )
        );
}
```

with the query json

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "term": {
          "productTypeID": {
            "value": 2
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "stocks.statusID": {
                      "value": 1
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "stocks.checkStockStatus": {
                            "value": false
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "term": {
                                "stocks.checkStockStatus": {
                                  "value": true
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "range": {
                                "stocks.currentStockCount": {
                                  "gt": 0.0
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "path": "stocks"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Russ, I changed the code with the last code you provided, it generates the same query as you told but it doesn't work somehow. When I check the data it should return at least 1018 results but it doesn't return anything at all. I'm not familiar with elasticsearch query structure so I can not understand what is wrong. So, what can I try now to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Did you map `stocks` as a `nested` type? It won't work if it's not a `nested` type. You may need to reindex the data into a new index with a new mapping that maps `stocks` as a `nested` type

Comment: I'm going to try that, now I have one more question. I have a <List> guid property called categoryids. It contains category ids of a product. lets say 1,2 as a value to simplify it. I want to query a list of values to match at least one of them. I mean for example I will pass 1,3,4 to search and it should return products which has 1 or 3 or 4 (at least one of them) should be in categoryids values. Should I map categoryids propery as nested as well? how can I query that? thank you.

Comment: You should _really_ ask that as a separate question :) No, you don't need to map that as `nested`; `nested` types are really for when you wish to perform compound queries across the properties of `nested` types. There's only one property of guids i.e. the guid value itself, that you can query on, so `categoryIds` should not be mapped as `nested`. You probably want to map it as `not_analyzed` though as you're likely doing structured queries (e.g. `term` queries) on them.

Comment: can you please help me with <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697563/how-to-search-array-property-by-array-in-elasticsearch-with-nest-client>?