# How to search array property by array in elasticsearch with nest client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Lets say we have a class called acls and this class has a List property called lprop.

Now lets say I have another List which has values 1,3,5 and lets say this variables name is tosearch.

I want to search tosearch values in acls typed records lprop property in an index of elasticsearch by using nest and finding only one match is sufficient.

Ex:

```
    `public class acls
    {
        public List<int> lprop {get;set;}
    }
    public void main()
    {
        //.. creating connection and etc..
        // we have 3 recs of acls
        // 1. lprop values: 2,4,6,8
        // 2. lprop values: 1,9,0,4
        // 3. lprop values: 6,7,8
        List<int> tosearch = new int[] { 1, 3, 5 }.ToList();
        //Now I want to search tosearch values in acls lprop values.
        // Result should be: 2. records
    }`
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [`Terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/terms-list-query-usage.html)

```
client.Search<acls>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Terms(c => c
            .Field(p => p.lprop)
            .Terms<string>(tosearch)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: tosearch variable is List<int> which contains values to match, will 1 query sufficient or should I generate more terms queries and OR them?

Comment: `terms` query does an `OR` on the passed terms i.e. a document field only needs to match one term to be considered a match. The documentation has more details - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-query

Comment: could I use int instead of List<int> for tosearch value?

Comment: `Terms` can take an `IEnumerable<T>` or a `params T[]` so you can pass `n` number of `T` to `.Terms()`

Comment: @RussCam : is it compulsory to convert "toSearch" in string?

Comment: @gmd no, if you have a `List<int>`, then use `.Terms<int>(IEnumerable<int> terms)`